# How to extract common name from distinguished name using Go?

Tags: parsing, go, openssl, cryptography, x509

I have an x509 certificate's subject distinguished name (DN) from an X.509 certificate. I want to extract common name (CN) from it. Is there a way to do it via `crypto/x509` or any other library in Go?

For Example, if the subject's distinguished name is:

```
CN=AMA AMI SA APB MDE MADB MDS LE.AXVD-04954-19-17.,OU=Abc,O=DA.CB.AcbDinema.com,dnQualifier=PY0aT8abfcQeUyquTe4w5RVasfY=
```

then I want to extract common name (CN) part (`AMA AMI SA APB MDE MADB MDS LE.AXVD-04954-19-17.`) out of it.

Comment: @Mayank - I believe the CN is *`AMA AMI SA APB MDE MADB MDS LE.AXVD-04954-19-17.`* (including the period); and not just *`AMA AMI SA APB MDE MADB MDS LE`*. Also see [RFC 4514, Lightweight Directory Access Protocol (LDAP): String Representation of Distinguished Names](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4514.txt).

Comment: Thanks for the input @jww. Updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing in the Go standard library to parse it for you (it only handles ASN.1 encoded distinguished names), but you treat it as just a string and parse it yourself.

Here is an example using regexps. **A word of warning**: there is no guarantee that this will work in all cases. For example, I've seen cases of lowercase `CN`, or ordering may change, or just bad formatting.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    subjectString := "CN=AMA AMI SA APB MDE MADB MDS LE.AXVD-04954-19-17.,OU=Abc,O=DA.CB.AcbDinema.com,dnQualifier=PY0aT8abfcQeUyquTe4w5RVasfY="
    re := regexp.MustCompile("CN=([^,]+)")
    matches := re.FindStringSubmatch(subjectString)

    fmt.Println(matches[1])

    commonNameParts := strings.Split(matches[1], " ")
    fmt.Println(commonNameParts)
}
```

Outputs the full CN string and a slice of the individual components of the CommonName:

```
AMA AMI SA APB MDE MADB MDS LE.AXVD-04954-19-17.
[AMA AMI SA APB MDE MADB MDS LE.AXVD-04954-19-17.]
```

Comment: I don't believe *"The ... subject or issuer [distinguished name] is not supposed to be passed around and parsed, it's purely for human convenience."* is correct. The distinguished name if effectively a key into the directory or database. It is used to uniquely identify the entity or object. Also see [RFC 4514](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4514.txt).

Comment: The warning included in your answer "there is no guarantee that this will work in all cases", is what I am trying to avoid by asking for a well-tested package to do it for me. Thanks for your time though.

Comment: I'm not aware of any libraries in Go to do this for you. asking for library recommendations is also off-topic on SO.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a function I wrote to solve this problem if you have just the string such as:
`C=US, O="Cloudflare, Inc.", CN=Cloudflare Inc ECC CA-3`

```
func parseIssuerDn(issuer string) map[string]string {

    trackerResultMap := map[string]string{"C=": "", "O=": "", "CN=": "", "ST=": "", "L=": "", "OU=": ""}

    for tracker, _ := range trackerResultMap {
        index := strings.Index(issuer, tracker)

        if index < 0 {
            continue
        }

        var res string

        // track quotes for delimited fields so we know not to split on the comma
        quoteCount := 0

        for i := index + len(tracker); i < len(issuer); i++ {

            char := issuer[i]

            // if ", we need to count and delimit
            if char == 34 {
                quoteCount++
                if quoteCount == 2 {
                    break
                } else {
                    continue
                }
            }

            // comma, lets stop here but only if we don't have quotes
            if char == 44 && quoteCount == 0 {
                break
            }

            // add this individual char
            res += string(rune(char))

        }

        trackerResultMap[strings.TrimSuffix(tracker, "=")] = strings.TrimPrefix(res, "=")
    }

    for k, v := range trackerResultMap {
        if len(v) == 0 {
            delete(trackerResultMap, k)
        }
    }

    return trackerResultMap
}
```